# ul li image to fill the div

Tags: css

I have a page with 2 columns. The first column is `30%` of the width and the second column `70%` with the thumbnails for a slide show. Here is the second column:

[image: here is the second column]

I want the thumbnails to fill the screen, as you can on the bottom the part is left out.

This is what I have

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="rig">
  <li>Image 1</li>
  <li>Image 2</li>
  <li>Image 3</li>
  <li>Image 4</li>
  <li>Image 5</li>
  <li>Image 6</li>
  <li>Image 7</li>
  <li>Image 8</li>
  <li>Image 9</li>
 </ul>
</div>

.wrapper {
    max-height: inherit;
    max-width: inherit;
}

.rig {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    max-height: 100%;
   }

.rig li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:33.33%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

What I want is for the thumbnail to fill the screen without the red part.
Is there a way to specify the height of the `li` elements?
Basically, I want the widths to be `33.33%` and the height as `33.33%` of its parent container . I don't want to specify it in pixels...

Comment: Set `height: 33.33%`. You should post more because this says nothing to me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolve. thanks for the help . resolved using     `height: calc(100vh / 3);`